# Return a dictionary

Tags: python, return

I'm having some trouble returning the dictionary that I build inside the `report` function. I known that I'm actually calling the `decode` function. I just can't figure out how to solve this. Everything works fine. The code does what it is supposed. But then, I added this dictionary that I would like to return so I could use it in `script_A.py`

Calling code (sript_A.py):

```
self.decoder = Decoder(Frame)
recvDict = self.decoder.decode(self.message)
print type(recvDict) # this returns <type 'NoneType'>
```

Called code (script_B.py):

```
class Decoder(object):
    def decode(self, message):
        processIncomingPacket(message, self.report)

    def report(self, message):
        my_dict = {'a': '123', 'b': '456'}
        return my_dict
```

Some other script where `processIncomingPacket` is defined:

```
class Some_class(object):
    processIncomingPacket(self, data, callback):
        raise NotImplementedException("not implemented")
```

**UPDATED:**

The implementation for `processIncomingPacket`:

```
def processIncomingPacket(self, data, callback):
    _logger.debug(" ".join([hex(ord(x)) for x in data]))
    self.addToFrame(data)
    while self.isFrameReady():
        if self.checkFrame():
            result = self.decoder.decode(self.getFrame())
            if result is None:
                raise PacketIOException("Unable to decode request")
            self.populateResult(result)
            self.advanceFrame()
            callback(result)  # defer or push to a thread?
        else: break
```

Comment: It looks like you need to do: `return processIncomingPacket(message, self.report)` inside the `decode` function.

Comment: @iCodez I tried that and does not work :(

Comment: @vgo Can you share the *actual* implementation of `processIncomingPacket`? Specifically the place where it executes `callback`?

Comment: @dano That is exactly the implementation. It only raises an exception.

Comment: @vgo In that case, something isn't adding up here. You're calling `self.decoder.decode(...)`, which is calling `processIncomingPacket`, which is raising an exception. Yet you're saying your code isn't raising an exception, it's just returning `None`.

Comment: You are right @dano. Sorry. I updated the post with the implementation for `processIncomingPacket`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `processIncomingPacket` doesn't return the result of the callback you pass to it (`self.result`, in your case):

```
self.populateResult(result)
self.advanceFrame()
callback(result)  # Doesn't capture the return value
```

The simplest fix is to adjust how your callback works, so that it doesn't need to return anything. Instead, have it take an existing dict object and just update that with the contents you want:

```
from functools import partial

class Decoder(object):
    def decode(self, message, recvDict):
        callback = partial(self.report, recvDict)
        processIncomingPacket(message, callback)

    def report(self, recvDict, message):
        my_dict = {'a': '123', 'b': '456'}
        recvDict.update(my_dict)

self.decoder = Decoder(Frame)
recvDict = {}
self.decoder.decode(self.message, recvDict)
# recvDict now matches my_dict
```

Comment: Thank you! I have never heard about functools. It does seem to do what I want. At least now when I `print type(recvDict)` after the `self.decoder.decode(self.message, recvDict)` line, it says it is a dictionary. However, When I `print recvDict` it shows me an empty dict `{}`. Any idea why?

Comment: @vgo Sorry, I had reversed the parameters in the `report` function. Should be good now.

Answer (score 1):

The processIncomingPacket seems to be doing nothing but raise an exception.

```
class Some_class(object):
    processIncomingPacket(self, data, callback):
       raise NotImplementedException("not implemented")
```

I believe you need to fix the implementation of the processIncomingPacket to act on the parameters passed and return the dictionary.